# How to remove automatic labels created from pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When plotting columns of a pandas.DataFrame they get their label automatically from the column name. Now it might be, that one wants to plot the same colum more than one time (e.g. once resampled or as a rolling mean and once the original curve in the background) - see example below - and label only one of them. This might be reached by mixing pandas and matplotlib plotting commands (hybrid). 
1) Is there a different way (by deactivating the automatic label of the pandas.DataFrame.plot command, or by dropping those items from the legend)?
2) If this is not possible by using only pandas and I need to mix them, how could I get a plot with the legend shown by "matplotlib.pyplot.plot" and the intelligent pandas x DatetimeIndex labels?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods = 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 5), columns = ['1st','2nd','3rd','4th','5th'], index = index)

df['2nd'] = df['2nd']+5

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(df['1st'], color ='grey')
plt.plot(pd.rolling_mean(df['1st'],window = 60, center = True), color ='b', label='rm_1st')

plt.plot(df['2nd'], color ='grey')
plt.plot(pd.rolling_mean(df['2nd'],window = 60, center = True), color ='r', label='rm_2nd')
plt.title('matplotlib.pyplot.plot')
plt.legend()

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.plot(df['1st'], color ='grey')
plt.plot(pd.rolling_mean(df['1st'],window = 60, center = True), color ='b', label='rm_1st')

plt.plot(df['2nd'], color ='grey')
plt.plot(pd.rolling_mean(df['2nd'],window = 60, center = True), color ='r', label='rm_2nd')
plt.title('matplotlib.pyplot.plot')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(1,3,2)
df['1st'].plot( color ='grey')
pd.rolling_mean(df['1st'],window = 60, center = True).plot(color ='b', label='rm_1st')

df['2nd'].plot(color ='grey')
pd.rolling_mean(df['2nd'],window = 60, center = True).plot(color ='r', label='rm_2nd')
plt.title('pandas.DataFrame.plot')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.plot(df['1st'].index, df['1st'], color ='grey')
pd.rolling_mean(df['1st'],window = 60, center = True).plot(color ='b', label='rm_1st')

plt.plot(df['2nd'].index, df['2nd'],color ='grey')
pd.rolling_mean(df['2nd'],window = 60, center = True).plot(color ='r', label='rm_2nd')
plt.title('hybrid')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Try setting the `label=''`